# Lorenz attractor as a position-velocity-acceleration problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

Considering the following Lorentz's attractor,

$$\begin{aligned}
&\dot x=\sigma (y-x)\\ 
&\dot y=x(\rho -z)-y\\
&\dot z=xy-\beta z
\end{aligned}$$

I would like to convert it to a position-velocity-acceleration problem (via variable changes) as follows:

$$\begin{aligned}
&\dot p=v\\ 
&\dot v=a\\
&\dot a=???
\end{aligned}$$

The jerk $\dot a$ is a function of acceleration $a$, velocity $v$ and position $p$. I look for a non-trivial solution which do not loose the information of the original problem.

Can anyone please help such a conversion?

Comment: I know about representation of form $\ddot{x} = f(x, \dot{x}, u), \dot{u} = g(x, u)$. Would this be useful to you or you want only position-velocity-acceleration representation?

Comment: Not every coupled system, especially if it is non-linear, can be transformed into a scalar ODE, which is what you are trying to achieve in finding the first-order system of such a scalar higher order ODE. Please state why you think this is possible or desirable in this case.

Comment: @LutzL Do you know the way how to tell for sure that system can't be transformed into a scalar equation?

Comment: @LutzL, if one find this, he can convert the equation into a single line with one equality sign. I also would like to know which acceleration law will create a similar chaos.

Comment: @Evgeny, what you are proposing is multi-variable. I look for converting it to a differential equation with only one single equality.

Comment: This version that I've mentioned has one physical appeal: it represents Lorenz system as a nonlinear oscillator one of which parameters depend on the state of the system. Also, there is [Arneodo-Coullet-Tresser system](http://sci-hub.tw/https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/037596017990464X) which is chaotic and has the form that you want.

Comment: And if I'm not confusing anything this article also has references for converting Lorenz into that form.

Comment: @Evgeny, is that one in the form of $\dddot x=f(x,\dot x,\ddot x)$ ?

Comment: I'll quote the article for you: "A compact form for eqs. (2) is $\dddot{x} + \beta \ddot{x} + \dot{x} = f_{\mu}(x)$". This refers to Arneodo-Coullet-Tresser systems. For Lorenz system this article has few references, so you can do research yourself using them as starting point. Or you can look at "eqs. (2)" and figure out can you do the same with eqs. (1).